# Does moment of inertia tensor keeps changing if object is rotating about multiple axes?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Consider a plane circular disc kept in X-Y plane with Z axis passing through its centre. It is rotated about all threes axes with some angular velocities. In such a case, to find the inertia tensor, do we have to take instantaneous moment of inertia as the position of the coordinates of the body keeps changing, hence leading to different inertia tensor, each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the MMOI tensor is to convert angular velocity vector, to angular momentum vector (both vectors on the same basis vectors).

But for a rigid body, the MMOI tensor is defined for body riding basis vector (fixed to the body), such that if you know the rotational velocity vector on the body coordinates you could write

$$ \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm body} = \mathbf{I}_{\rm body\,} \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm body} \tag{1}$$

Each of these two vectors can be re-oriented to the common inertial frame (world basis vectors) using the local-to-world 3×3 rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \boldsymbol{\omega} &= \mathbf{R}\,\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm body} \\
  \boldsymbol{L} &= \mathbf{R}\,\boldsymbol{L}_{\rm body} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

Not the inverse rotation transformation is $\mathrm{R}^\top$ so angular momentum in the world frame is

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \boldsymbol{L} & = \mathbf{R} \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm body} \\
   & = \mathbf{R} \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm body} \\
  & = \underbrace{\mathbf{R} \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \mathbf{R}^\top}_{\rm I} \boldsymbol{\omega} \\
 \boldsymbol{L} & = \mathbf{I}\, \boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{aligned}$$

So by definition

$$ \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{R} \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \mathbf{R}^\top$$ is the calculation of MMOI tensor on a general rotated state.

Answer (score 3):

first you obtain the inertia tensor in body fixed coordinate system (index B) ,then you can transformed the inertia tensor to  inertial system or any other system  (index I).

$$\mathbf I_I=\mathbf R\,\mathbf I_B\,\mathbf R^T$$

where the transformation matrix  $~\mathbf R=\mathbf R(\alpha\,,\beta\,,\gamma)~$
is a function of the Euler angles $~\alpha\,,\beta\,,\gamma~$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From the definition of angular momentum for a particle:

$$\mathbf L = \mathbf r \times \mathbf p$$

In the case of a rigid body, the distance between points are constant, what leads to the expression:

$$\mathbf L = \int \rho (\mathbf r \times \Omega \mathbf r)dV$$

where $\Omega$ is the intantaneous matriz of angular velocities, what means: infinitesimal rotation by infinitesimal time.

The cross product results in a column matriz:

$(y^2 + z^2)ω_1 -  xyω_2 – xzω_3$

$(z^2 + x^2)ω_2 -  yzω_3 – yxω_1$

$(x^2 + y^2)ω_3 -  zxω_1 – zyω_2$

After rearranging, it can be separated as a product of an $3 x 3$ square matriz by a $1 x 3$ column matriz (with the $3 \omega$'s). At each instant, the angular velocities are the same for all points of the rigid body, and it can be placed out of the integral.

The integral of the square matrix over the volume is the inertia matrix. And it changes in general with time.